# 'sudo dmidecode | grep UUID' and '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid'. Are they same?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, uuid, iaas

I need to register for monitoring purposes Linux servers running on real hardware as well as on virtual machines, AWS, Azure,.. by sending their unique id. I figured out that id given by

```
sudo dmidecode | grep UUID
```

is the best choice because its result is different even if you have cloned virtual machine without reinitialization of MAC address.

But **dmidecode** is not installed everywhere. So I'm trying to understand does file */sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid* **always** contains the same UUID as given by **dmidecode**?

Comment: It looks like `/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid` also contains UUID (the same on my machine), I don't know how it differs from `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid`...

Comment: `/sys/class/dmi/id` is a symbolic link to `../../devices/virtual/dmi/id` At least in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dmidecode | grep UUID` and `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid`should be equal but depending on your system the output can be different.

From dmidecode [source code](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/master/dmidecode.c#L415):

```
/*
 * As of version 2.6 of the SMBIOS specification, the first 3
 * fields of the UUID are supposed to be encoded on little-endian.
 * The specification says that this is the defacto standard,
 * however I've seen systems following RFC 4122 instead and use
 * network byte order, so I am reluctant to apply the byte-swapping
 * for older versions.
 */
```

See also: [[PATCH] dmi, Use little-endian for sysfs PRODUCT UUID](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1203.3/00670.html)

I notice that [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/e143d3a75b01afd8b7157e3fc08b2624db4f939e/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts.py#L1153) also try /sys first and  fall back to dmidecode executable to collect dmi related facts.